# Common modules in yiiboilerplate?

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, project-structure

Is it possible to put and run modules in yiiboilerplate common section?
If it could, how it configured?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just configure the module with a path alias, as far as I can tell there is an alias `root` which points to the project root.

```
'foo' => array(
    'class' => 'root.common.modules.foo.FooModule',
),
```

You may also have a look at [this config](https://github.com/phundament/app/blob/0fc0706888465d3f9d9cbdfea2fc12e43098209e/app/config/main.php#L76) file from my boilerplate, which does the same.